# Gradle dependency management based on build variant for java project

Tags: gradle

I am using gradle to build a java spring project. What I am trying to do is:

If build target is dev or not specified, use dependency

compile("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")

If build target is prod or qa, use dependency

compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31")

I am not sure how to do this in gradle. First thing is how to pass the build type variable to the build script. The second thing is how to write the conditional dependency code based on the variable? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`build.gradle` is a Groovy file, so you can use `if` statements to dynamically change your dependencies, like this:

```
dependencies {
   // other dependencies

   if (someFlag) {
       compile("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")
   } else {
       compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31")
   }
}
```

To configure something like this one may use [project properties](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/09/gradle-goodness-different-ways-to-set.html):

```
dependencies {
   // other dependencies

    if (!project.hasProperty("targetEnv") || targetEnv == "dev") {
        compile("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")
    } else if (targetEnv == "prod" || targetEnv == "qa") {
        compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31")
    } else {
        throw new InvalidUserDataException("Unknown target environment '$targetEnv'")
    }
}
```

And now mysql dependency will be used when gradle is run with `-PtargetEnv=qa` or `-PtargetEnv=prod`, hsqldb — for cases when `targetEnv` is not specified or set to `dev`, and finally exception will be thrown if some unknown environment name is passed.